# Adverb of duration

Tags: perfect-constructions, continuous, stative-verbs

an adverb of duration can tell us how long somebody does something for example:

> all morning/all night

> all week/ all month

> for days /for weeks

> The whole time

So I want to know which tense we can use with them.

We only use them with all continuous tense and stative verbs in simple form and perfect Tense; Right?

We don't use them in simple form except with stative verb; right?

Please correct me if I made a mistake.

Comment: You need to provide example sentences of your own. By just quoting a grammar book, we cannot tell what you mean. If you are using a phone rather than a computer to ask questions, your automatic text thing is making errors. Please see my edit above. Thanks.

Comment: Those are **phrases, not single word adverbs** like: always, sometimes, never (ever), frequently, often. And no, there is no rule about tenses. Is there in your language? She always cooks on Saturdays. [active verb + adverb]

Comment: https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/33113/lambie thank you, it was so helpful 

Comment: fatemeh, rather than put in a link to an avatar, use this button @, the at button, followed by the avatar.

Comment: @fatemehkhayat You probably mean 'adjunct', not 'adverb', since that is their normal function. Generally, such expressions can be used with any tense: "He stays for weeks" (present) / "He stayed all morning" (preterite) / "He has/had stayed all night" (perfect). Incidentally, the progressive is an aspect. not a tense.